# Maintain Html.BeginForm() route path format as / instead of?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want my form to maintain the path for the `<form action="">` as the url route provides it.

For example if the url is `/MyAction/asd`, the form action should be `<form action="/MyAction/asd" ...>`. I can achieve this by not giving any parameter to `using (Html.BeginForm())`. Similarly if there's no route value, it should be just `<form action="/MyAction" ...>`

But because I want to give the form element custom html attributes, I have to use `Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Controller", new {id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "password-handler" })`

This creates the following element: `<form action="MyAction?id=asd" method="post" id="password-handler">`

Comment: Just use `null` as the 3rd parameter. You can also use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary{System.String,System.Object}%29)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried that and it completely removes the attribute, that's the complete opposite of my needs

Comment: Then just use `null` in place of the 1st 2 parameters as well - `Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { ... })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get the same result, it writes just the action without the route `action="/MyAction"`

Comment: What is the signature of that method, and does it match a route definition (if the method is `public Action xxx(string id)` and you have the default route, then it will add the value in the `action` attribute. But if your claiming it generates `?id=asd"` (i.e a query string) then you must not have a matching route

Comment: I looked around a bit and it turns out there was some custom routing that didn't handle the POST action well. After correcting that, your solution works.